# Need help fixing my awful front lawn

Tags: weeds, landscaping

Just purchased this home and I don’t even know where to start, the front yard is full of weeds and rock. Any suggestions on easy cost effective fixes? [image]

Comment: Where in the world do you live?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Appears to be the sort of arid location where "lawn" is going to be a difficult and expensive choice. You might want to consider alternatives more suited to the local climate, if my take on the appearance is correct.

Comment: Looks like gravel would be good, maybe a few cacti.

Comment: If it's a place like Phoenix Arizona US, then a design incorporating an arroyo would be nice - similar to a pondless water feature in non-arid parts of the US, with some native catci, and a tree like an Arizona Cypress or maybe a Desert Willow.